# Visual Studio 2008 hot keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, visual-studio-2008

Where can I find a good cheat sheet for Visual Studio hot keys?  In particular I'm wanting to switch between tabs but I'd like to see other shortcuts too.

Comment: LOL when I read "hot keys" (as opposed to "hotkeys") I thought for a moment your question might be about stolen (hot) registration codes (keys) ;-)

Comment: funny.  not only are they stolen, they're sexy too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What language?

How about the [**Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en)

Or [**this one**](http://nerdfortress.s3.amazonaws.com/visual-studio-2008-keyboard-shortcuts.html) from Nerd Fortress.

Switching between tabs is done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to get the open tab popup and using the arrow keys or mouse to select the tab you want.

Also note that the keybindings can be overridden by plugins to VS such as Resharper or Coderush.  If you have anything like these tools then it's possible (likely) that the above references will be a bit invalidated.

Comment: wow, that ctrl-tab is pretty sweet

Answer (score 3):

The key bindings for Visual Studio 2008 change based on various settings (including initial setup, where you choose whether you develop in VB.NET, C#, etc., primarily).

[Here are posters](http://swami-k.blogspot.com/2009/01/visual-studio-2008-keyboard-shortcut.html) (for free download; up to you to print them) with the *default* C# and VB.NET key bindings.

Additionally, a few of my favorites:

- CTRL+K, CTRL+C: Comment selection
- CTRL+K, CTRL+U: Uncomment selection
- CTRL+PageDown: Switch between design, split and code views for HTML
- F5: I hope you know this one; build and run in debugger
- CTRL+K, CTRL+D: Format document

Answer (score 0):

Sara Ford of Microsoft produced a [Visual Studio 2008 Tip of the Day](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/tags/Visual+Studio+2008+Tip+of+the+Day/default.aspx) series.  There were nearly 400 tips and many of them dealt with various hot-keys.  The link will take you to the section of her blog that covers the tips.  That should get you into some very interesting and useful items.